# Generic LINQ Extension on dynamic Navigation property

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, generics, linq-to-sql

I have the following problem which I am not getting my head wrapped around for hours:

I have several Entities which I want to filter on. 
They all have a Navigation Property of Type *Person* in common - though its not called the same in all of these Entities.

The *Person* Entity has a List of *CompanyRelation*-Instances, which states what *Relation* the *Person* has to a *Company*

```
public class Person
{
   public Collection<CompanyRelation> CompanyRelations { get; set; }
}

public enum CompanyRelationType
{
    Employee,
    Manager
}

public class Contract
{
    public Person ContractCreator { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyRelation
{
    public virtual Guid PersonId { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public virtual CompanyRelationType RelationType { get; set; }
}
```

I now want to write a generic LINQ Extension, which can be used on any Entity-Collection and takes the Path to the Navigation Property and some static filter parameters. Since the Entities I query on have no common base, the LINQ Extension is generic on type T.

By now, I came up with something like this:

```
    public static IQueryable<T> HasRelation<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, Person>> personExpr, Guid companyId, CompanyRelationType relationType)
    {
        return query = query.Where(tc => tc.ContractCreator.CompanyRelations.Any(cr => cr.CompanyId == companyId));            
    }
```

The obvious problem here is that I dont have a Property "ContractCreator" in generic context of type T.

The Question here is now: How can I transform the personExpr, in which I define the path of the navigation property to a form I can write my filter query on and still works with LINQ to SQL.

I also tried it as lambda which I invoked with tc, but since invoke is not supported by LINQ to SQL, that didnt work either:

```
    public static IQueryable<T> HasRelation<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Func<T, Person> personExpr, Guid companyId, CompanyRelationType relationType)
    {
        return query = query.Where(tc => personExpr(tc).CompanyRelations.Any(cr => cr.CompanyId == companyId));            
    }
```

For completeness' sake and maybe for better understanding, here the way I call the extension:

```
Guid companyId = ... //Some Company's Id

var result = this.unitOfWork.Contracts      .HasAnyRelation(c => c.ContractCreator, companyId, CompanyRelationType.Employee);
```

I'm really looking forward to your answers!

Comment: Are you open for 3rd party libraries or you want a local solution?

Comment: As long as the 3rd party lib is free for commercial use and provides a significant improval to the local solution, I would consider using it. I already integrated LinqKit, if this is of any help.

Comment: It definitely does help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) `AsExpandable` and `Invoke` extension methods like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> HasRelation<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, Person>> personExpr, Guid companyId, CompanyRelationType relationType)
{
    return query.AsExpandable().Where(tc => 
        personExpr.Invoke(tc).CompanyRelations.Any(cr => cr.CompanyId == companyId));            
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I first tried out the solution before your Edit to Expression, but already figured it out :)